# Flash AS3 sorton() difficulty

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, flash, sorting

I'm struggling on this. I've gone through other questions here and as far as I can tell I'm doing what I'm supposed to. Seems like it should be simple enough, but I'm still hung up. Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
    <player>
        <score Name="Josh" Company="AB" Email="josh@ab">200</score>
    </player>
    <player>
        <score Name="Shain" Company="AC" Email="shain@AC.com">1800</score>
    </player>
    <player>
        <score Name="Jessica" Company="AD" Email="jessica@AD.com">20000</score>
    </player>

</objects>
```

And here's my code. I'm putting the XML "scores" data into an Array "myArray" with the "for each" loop, and that traces fine, but the sort isn't sorting them by scores as it should be.

```
var myArray:Array = new Array();

    for each (var item:XML in scores)
    {
        myArray.push(item);
    }
    trace("pre-sort "+myArray);

    myArray.sortOn("score", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);

    trace("post-sort "+myArray);
```

Again, this seems really simple, but I'm beating my head against the keyboard on it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not good with XML but this seems to work for me. I just changed the scores to scores.children().

```
var scores:XML = <objects>
        <player>
          <score Name="Josh" Company="AB" Email="josh@ab">200</score>
        </player>
        <player>
          <score Name="Shain" Company="AC" Email="shain@AC.com">1800</score>
        </player>
        <player>
          <score Name="Jessica" Company="AD" Email="jessica@AD.com">20000</score>
        </player>
        </objects>;

var myArray:Array = new Array();

for each (var item:XML in scores.children())
{
    myArray.push(item);
}
trace("pre-sort "+myArray);

myArray.sortOn("score", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);

trace("post-sort "+myArray);
```

Comment: That was it! I was missing the ".children()" Thanks Baris!

Answer (score 0):

Well [sortOn](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html) is for sorting an Array filled by Objects and based on a property field, but you are filling the array with XML node and there is no property directly named 'score' on these node.

You can use the function sort by itself to get the result you want.

```
var xml:XML=
<objects>
    <player>
        <score Name="Josh" Company="AB" Email="josh@ab">200</score>
    </player>
    <player>
        <score Name="Shain" Company="AC" Email="shain@AC.com">1800</score>
    </player>
    <player>
        <score Name="Jessica" Company="AD" Email="jessica@AD.com">20000</score>
    </player>
</objects>;

var myArray=[];
for each (var score:XML in xml..score) {
 myArray[myArray.length] = score;
}

myArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
trace("post-sort "+myArray);
```

Here a live example on wonderfl:
http://wonderfl.net/c/c6av